# How to redo equation upon page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a page that does a page refresh every 15 seconds to collect API data, this data is presented in a chart based on the time of day. There is a button that when clicked will do some math on `val1` however once the page resets the value goes back to the API data, which I dont want to happen so long as reset button has not been clicked. 
HTML:

```
th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
id="hotButton"
ng-click="img_base = img_evening; val1 = (RTeve *6.026); val2=SolarEve; val3=BatteryEve; TOD = hotmode"
onclick="changeColor('black', 'SC'),
```

Here is the AngularJS:

```
$scope.getBooks = function(){
    $http.get('http://localhost:5000').then(function(resp){

        var neurio = resp['data'][0];
        var sensep = resp['data'][1];
        var eagle = resp['data'][2];
        var ICeagle = resp['data'][3];

        var Cur_eagle = resp['data'][4];
        var Eagle2 = resp['data'][5]; //efergy eagle, does not exist yet

        var smappee = resp['data'][6];
        var efergy = resp['data'][7];

        var arrayForHouse = [neurio, sensep, eagle, efergy, smappee];       

        $scope.SolarMor = ((3.6374) *0.4).toFixed(2); 
        $scope.SolarAft = (3.6374).toFixed(2);
        $scope.SolarEve = 0.73;

        $scope.BatteryMor = "Discharge";
        $scope.BatteryAft = "Charge";
        $scope.BatteryEve = "Discharge";


        if (day_night<11 && day_night>=1) 
        {       
            $scope.RTmor = ((neurio + sensep + efergy + smappee + residentialHome)/1000).toFixed(2);
            $scope.RTaft = (((neurio + sensep + efergy + smappee + residentialHome)*1.32)/1000).toFixed(2);
            $scope.RTeve = (((neurio + sensep + efergy + smappee + residentialHome) * 1.95)/1000).toFixed(2);

            $scope.val1 = $scope.RTmor;
            $scope.val2 = $scope.SolarMor;
            $scope.val3 = $scope.BatteryMor;

            $scope.resetGD = $scope.RTmor;
            $scope.resetSolar = $scope.SolarMor;
            $scope.resetBat = $scope.BatteryMor;


        } 
        else if (day_night >=11 && day_night < 17)
        {
            $scope.RTmor = (((neurio + sensep + efergy + smappee + residentialHome) * 0.76)/1000).toFixed(2);
            $scope.RTaft = ((neurio + sensep + efergy + smappee + residentialHome)/1000).toFixed(2);
            $scope.RTeve = (((neurio + sensep + efergy + smappee + residentialHome) * 1.45)/1000).toFixed(2);

            $scope.val1 = $scope.RTaft;
            $scope.val2 = $scope.SolarAft;
            $scope.val3 = $scope.BatteryAft;

            $scope.resetGD = $scope.RTaft;
            $scope.resetSolar = $scope.SolarAft;
            $scope.resetBat = $scope.BatteryAft;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.RTmor = (((neurio + sensep + efergy + smappee + residentialHome) * 0.52)/1000).toFixed(2);
            $scope.RTaft = (((neurio + sensep + efergy + smappee + residentialHome)*0.69)/1000).toFixed(2);
            $scope.RTeve = ((neurio + sensep + efergy + smappee + residentialHome)/1000).toFixed(2);

            $scope.val1 = $scope.RTeve;
            $scope.val2 = $scope.SolarEve;
            $scope.val3 = $scope.BatteryEve;

            $scope.resetGD = $scope.RTeve;
            $scope.resetSolar = $scope.SolarEve;
            $scope.resetBat = $scope.BatteryEve;
        }

    });
}

    $scope.getBooks();
    $interval($scope.getBooks,15000); 
});
```

In the ng-click there is a `val1 = (RTeve*6.026)` It is ok if this data is updated upon refresh, but right now I am unable to get the 6.026 to refresh with it.

This is because ng-click has happened and once the page is refreshed, val1 is reset as well until another click happens...

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I would strongly advise you not to put all that logic directly in the HTML markup. You should be calling a method in the controller.

Comment: @Lex that makes sense, but is there a way to see that a button has been clicked in the controller? thats the problem Im  having.

Comment: You could have a boolean value in your controller to indicate that.

Comment: You also shouldn't be refreshing the entire page. That totally defeats the purpose of a single-page app. It's the scenario which the likes of AngularJS were created to avoid. Just make your api call and update the data that's bound to the view.